# Wiring an EE42-1200w transformer

Tags: transformer, wiring

I have a ferrite core transformer with 6 pins on on side and 4 on the other. How do I wire it for 110-240 VAC in to 12-24 V out?

The transformer is called EE42-1200w there is a picture on this page: https://m.made-in-china.com/product/Electric-SMPS-Flyback-Ferrite-Core-Power-Ee40-Ee42-Ee49-Ee19-High-Frequency-Transformer-791962642.html

Comment: Measure resistance between every pair of pins that measure a non-infinite resistance  and come back with a labeled diagram. No guarantee it is 10:1 unless you already know it is.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the transformer?  Or know the make and model/part number?  Even a clear photo may help someone identify it.

Comment: the transformer is called EE42-1200w            there is a picture on this page https://m.made-in-china.com/product/Electric-SMPS-Flyback-Ferrite-Core-Power-Ee40-Ee42-Ee49-Ee19-High-Frequency-Transformer-791962642.html

Comment: It is a high frequency transformer. It will not work on 50/60Hz.

Comment: WARNING - AS PER OTHER COMMENTS AND ANSWER - THIS PRODUCT **CANNOT** BE USED DIRECTLY ON AC MAINS.  A properly designed power supply circuit is required.

Answer (score 4):

Only a transformer with a core made up of silicon steel laminations would be suitable for 50/60 Hz operation in a linear power supply.

A ferrite core transformer, on the other hand, would be suitable for use in a switch mode power supply operating at 15 - 50 kHz.

Here's the block diagram of a linear regulated power supply.

[image]

Both the step-down transformer, that sources the output current, and the filter would be quite bulky as they would be operating at 50 / 60 Hz.

Here's the block diagram of a switch mode power supply.

[image]

In this case both the step-down transformer, that sources the output current, and the filter would be quite compact as they would be operating at 15 - 50 kHz.